# spring boot how to define property file for all controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In spring boot I want define @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties") globally for all controller

how to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

add this annotation

> @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")

Over your @SpringBootApplication class (main class)